# Flex error: "access to undefined property"

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, properties, gsap

I'm trying to fix all the bugs for a flex project, and I don't get it. What's the problem with this snippet?

```
import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin;

private function initApp():void {   
  TweenPlugin.activate([BlurFilterPlugin]);
}
```

This is the error I get:

`error: 1120: Access to undefined property TweenPlugin.`

Comment: Do you have the greensock library placed in your "compiled" directory for your project?

Comment: its inside the flex directory... /flex/greensock.swc ---- /flex/src/my.mxml is that correct?

Comment: No, they should be in your flex/lib folder. That's probably why it's not importing properly in your Flex Project. The "lib" folder is what the default Flex project uses for "compiled libraries". Hence, the "lib".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only thing I can think of; make sure you are actually including the tweenplugin.swc in the project. You actually have to add it yourself, it doesn't happen automatically.

If you're using Flash CS5:
File -> Publish Settings -> Flash tab -> Settings button -> Library path tab -> "+" Button -> "lib/tweenplugin.swc" (if you put it in a lib folder).

In flash builder it's in compiler settings, paths and add swc file.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possibly because TweenPlugin doesn't have an activate() method? http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/plugins/TweenPlugin.html

Comment: What you say is true, but that's probably not the issue.  The error would be "Call to a possibly undefined method activate through a reference with static type Class."

Comment: This is why static Classes are such a PIA.

Answer (score -1):

Try placing your activate command with your imports:

```
import com.greensock.layout.*;
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;

TweenPlugin.activate([BlurFilterPlugin]);
```

Comment: Progress then! ;P

Make sure you have the latest and complete set of greensock classes by re-downloading them from greensock.com.

Try creating a new .fla file containing the above code and saving it next to your com directory which contains the greensock classes.

Test test the movie to see if the error still exists.

Comment: -1: One might be able to add code like this to a frame in Flash Pro, but that's just not how things work in Flex.  Unless you seriously know what your dependencies are, you shouldn't attempt to invoke methods before the `initialize` event, which is the signal that indicates that the framework has actually loaded.  The only reason code like this flies in Flash Pro is because it is essentially being invoked on the first "enterFrame" event.